# Different colors for ribbons in stat_summary using groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I'm trying to show mean and standard deviation of a dataset, where I want to display the std as a ribbon. The dataset is divided into three groups, where the mean is displayed in three different colors as intended, but the std-ribbon is not.

The code:

```
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

plot1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear, y=hp, color=cyl)) + geom_point() +
          stat_summary(geom='ribbon', fun.data = mean_cl_normal, fun.args=list(conf.int=0.95)) +
          stat_summary(geom='line', fun.y = mean, size=1)
plot1
```

I don't have enough reputation to post images, but the ribbons are all black. I'm confused as to why the mean lines seem to map perfectly to the three groups defined by the cyl-factor and the lines have three colors, while the ribbons do not.

Edit:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to colour the ribbons you need to add a `fill` aesthetic (distinct from `col`):

```
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

plot1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear, 
                            y=hp,
                            color=cyl,  # color gives colour of lines and borders
                            fill = cyl)) +  # fill colours the ribbons and other shapes
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(geom='ribbon', 
               fun.data = mean_cl_normal, 
               fun.args=list(conf.int=0.95),
               alpha = 0.5) +  # added transparency
  stat_summary(geom='line',
               fun.y = mean, size=1)

plot1
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @tbaek - has this helped? Do close the question if so, or respond here with any further help needed. Helps others who might be looking for similar answers.

Comment: Thank you! That is all I needed, and it makes sense. Thanks again.